# Eclipse IBM Webshpere startup Could not find or load main class VS

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

When starting up my IBM websphere 8.5 server on eclipse (both neon and 2020) I have the error "Could not find or load main class VS" on the server laucher console.
Then the startup does nothing until the timeout.

What can it be?
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: EDIT: the start doesn't work only from eclipse. Using the bat provided byy IBM (startServer.bat), the server starts with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to run WebSphere Application Server in Eclipse is to install the [WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/t_install_wdt_eclipse.html) and use the server view to create an instance of a WAS server.  You can then stop and start it from Eclipse.